# How to display current PDF page number and save this number as a bookmark in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, ipad

I’m new in swift and I’m working on my first app. The app is displaying a pdf file for the holy Qur’an have index which must connect every Surah (chapter) to it’s specific page in the pdf file and every page must have it’s number to make it a bookmark .

NOW I finished displaying  THE PDF FILE 
AND I NEED HELP TO SHOW THE USER THE NUMBER OF THE CURRENT PAGE EVERY SINGLE SWIPE

//here’s WHAT I Have Done

```
import UIKit
import PDFKit
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var pdfView2: PDFView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Binder1", ofType: ".pdf") {
            let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
            if let pdfDocument = PDFDocument(url: url) {
                pdfView2.displaysRTL = true
                pdfView2.autoScales = true
                pdfView2.displayMode = .singlePageContinuous
                pdfView2.displayDirection = .horizontal
                pdfView2.document = pdfDocument
                pdfView2.pageBreakMargins = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
                pdfView2.usePageViewController(true)
               navigationController?.hidesBarsOnTap = true
                pdfView2.usePageViewController(true)
                pdfView2.displaysAsBook = true
                pdfView2.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.95, alpha: 1.0)
                print(pdfDocument.index(for: pdfView2.currentPage!))

            }
         } 
      }

  }
```

[image]

IN THIS CIRCLE THE LABEL I NEED TO SHOW THE NUMBER AND THE TITLE OF EVERY PAGE

Answer (score 2):

To get the current page number

```
let pageNumber = pdfDocument.index(for: pdfView2.currentPage!)
```

And you can display it at the top like:

```
self.navigationItem.title = String(pageNumber)
```

If you want to store this number as bookmark persistently, you can use **UserDefaults**. Like:

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(pageNumber, forKey: "bookmarkedPage") // you can change the key
```

To get this value later on:

```
let savedPageNumber = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "bookmarkedPage")
```

After getting bookmark, to navigate to saved page in PDFView:

```
 pdfView2.go(to: pdfDocument?.page(at:savedPageNumber))
```